# Can I apply for a Thai visa from Australia as a non-resident?

Tags: visas, australia, residency

I am Nepalese citizen (Nepalese passport bearer) in Australia on a Tourist Visa , I'm palling to visit Thailand on my way home to Nepal.

Can I apply for a Thai Visa from Australia?

Answer (score 1):

No, only Australian residents can apply for a Thai visa in Australia.

Citizens of Nepal and 28 other countries need to use [Form B](http://www.thaiconsulatesydney.org/Content/attach-file/VISA_FORM_B_FINAL_NOV2015.pdf). Part C of the form says,

> ::: IMPORTANT NOTE ::: An applicant must hold a valid Australian Permanent or Temporary Resident visa only. However, some certain categories of visass [sic] are not accepted, for example, Business Short Stay 456 Visa, Visitor Visa, ect [sic]

Citizens of countries other than the 29 Form-B countries use [Form A](http://www.thaiconsulatesydney.org/Home/DownloadForm/5142727775); they are also required to be resident in Australia.

Comment: Thanks David, I did see this important note on Form B. What has me perplexed is this statement from the - www.thaiconsulatemelbourne.com/ site ' From now on-wards the passport or travel document holders of the following countries can ONLY obtain a visa to enter Thailand in Australia from The Royal Thai Embassy in Canberra - irrespective of their residence status in Australia.' of which Nepal is listed. This then loops back to Form B, which as you've stated has the important note regarding the Visitor's visa.

Comment: @Nick Well, it would have helped if you'd included that information in the question! As it is, I saw your question, thought "Surely that information is on the embassy website" and looked it up. If your question had made it clear that specialist knowledge was required, I wouldn't have spent my time telling you what you already know.